# Windows 2008 R2 Standard scheduled task stopped working - Last run result 0x2

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I have been scratching my head over this for a few days and can't get to the bottom of it. 
I have a scheduled task that runs a batch file every morning. The batch file starts a windows service which calls a web service on another server which then performs various tasks after which the service is stopped.

This has been working without issue for the last few months, but starting last week, every morning the scheduled task is triggered at the appointed time, but it's not starting the service and the Last Run Result is 0x2.

I've tried just about everything I could think of, checked 'Run whether user is logged in or not', 'Run with highest privileges'. I've turned on History for scheduled tasks and everything seems to run fine. There are no errors in Event Viewer nor is the service throwing any exceptions. Running the batch file manually executes just fine.

In the end I deleted and recreated the scheduled task which resolved the issue. Today this error started occurring again. I've been unable to get solid info on what exactly 0x2 means. Does any one have any more information on what could be the cause of this issue?

**I've come to believe that the issue lies with the server and not the service. I exported the service from Task Scheduler and imported again with no changes and it's been running fine over the weekend. Apparently some server maintenance was carried out around the time that the issue started occurring so will investigate further with our server management department**

Comment: Have you tried to run the batch under the same context as the scheduled task?

Comment: Yes, I have. Runs perfect

Comment: Have you tried to look at the batch file and play with it's advanced settings, i.e. on the actual batch file - "elevated privilages", etc.

Comment: Task Scheduler doesn't have network access when using the system account.  Test that by using your login credentials in the task and then manually launch the scheduled task.

Answer (score 1):

0x2 result means that the file could not be found.

Make sure that when the Task starts (which is apparently the case), the batch file exists and is accessible.

See System errors code [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I have checked that link in my quest for what 0x2 means. The file is definitely there, it hasn't moved since it was first ran on the server. I have also read numerous posts that 0x2 has to do with outdated certificates on the server so I'm a bit at a loss as there seems to be more than one meaning to the error code

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](http://www.kineticcomputer.com/tips/1401-last-run-result-(0x2)-in-task-scheduler-as-administrator.htm) 0x2 could also mean "Access denied". So maybe you are facing a permission issue.

You can try to configure the Scheduled Task to **Run with highest privileges** in the *Properties* dialog of the task (*General* tab).